# Синтаксическая ошибка php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Помогите пожалуйста. Возникает синтаксическая ошибка на строке 6. Вот код:

```
require_once 'config.php';
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '1'";    -- ОШИБКА ТУТ

$connect->exec($sql);
```

C запросом все хорошо.

Comment: простите, сейчас укажу строку

Comment: указал строку где ошибка

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а текст ошибки....это одна из важнейших деталей........скорее всего надо передавать int а ты передаёшь string  для  id

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/u175312/data/www/tech.loc/article.php on line 6

Comment: ошибка вот тут..

Comment: такой ошибки там быть не может при указанной строке..... скорее всего там другая строка, не та, что в вопросе

Comment: а как передать инт

Comment: я все перепробывал, не работает

Comment: читай ответ дубликат.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое

Comment: не выходит что от

Comment: <?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    $post_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

    $con->exec("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id`=$post_id");

    $title = '';
    $text = '';
?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$con' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/u179/data/www/vds.loc/article.php on line 6 (переменная con)

Comment: все варианты не подходят